# resume function on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am working on a page with javascript/jQuery and am almost finished. I am supposed to have rotating content (the function 'rotatecontent') and divs which show up in the rotating content's place when the relevant button is hovered over. 
I have accomplished all this except when I hover away from a button, all div content disappears and the original rotatecontent function does not resume. I need to implement a function to have it resume once a user hovers away from the button. Here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var messages;
var curcontentindex = 0;
var prevcontentindex;
var futcontentindex;
var i;



function rotatecontent() {
messages.hide();
curcontentindex = (curcontentindex < messages.length - 1) ? curcontentindex + 1 : 0;
messages.get(curcontentindex).style.display = "block";
}


$(function() {
messages = $('.dyncontent').find('div');
i = setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000);


$('li').hover(
function () {
$(this).addClass("hover");
clearInterval(i); // when mouse is over object
},
function () {
$(this).removeClass("hover");
setInterval(rotatecontent, 1000); //when mouse is no longer over object
}
);

});




</script>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="dyncontent">
<div id="div1">Be A Billiken </div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 3</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 4</div>
<div id="div5" style="display:none">Be A Billiken 5</div>
</div>



<ul id="container" overflow:hidden>

<li><a href="#" onMouseOver="$('div.dyncontent').replaceWith($('#div1').show());" onMouseOut=""><img     src="../Work/Images/BAB.com_web_link_10.jpg"  width="250" height="100" class="Bab-image"></a></li>


<li><a href="#" onMouseOver="$('div.dyncontent').replaceWith($('#div2').show());" onMouseOut=""><img     src="../Work/Images/SLU_on_the_Road.jpg" class="sluotr-image">    </a></li>

<li><a href="#" onMouseOver="$('div.dyncontent').replaceWith($('#div3').show());"     onMouseOut=""><img src="http://slu.edu/Images/graduate/Billiken_Blogs.jpg" class="blogs-    image"></a></li>

<li ><a href="#" onMouseOver="$('div.dyncontent').replaceWith($('#div4').show());"     onMouseOut=""><img src="http://slu.edu/Images/graduate/SLU_Chat.jpg" class="chat-image">    </a></li>

<li><a href="#" onMouseOver="$('div.dyncontent').replaceWith($('#div5').show());"     onMouseOut=""><img src="http://slu.edu/Images/graduate/Viewbook_Button_2011.jpg"     class="view-image"></a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: you have a lot of issues in your markup (excess space, missing attribute names, incorrect capitalization) is this a copy/paste of your actual code?

Comment: You can change `messages.get(curcontentindex).style.display = "block";` to `messages.eq(curcontentindex).show();`. Has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery `.hover()` function has a special structure which allows you to set what happens once the mouse is over the object, and what happens after the mouse is no longer pointing to the object.

```
$(".class").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover"); // when mouse is over object
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover"); //when mouse is no longer over object
  }
);
```

Save the original settings and then use them in the 'mouse-not-over' section

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the original settings? Do you mean the markup inside the onMouseOver section?

Comment: By original settings I mean the objects settings before they have been changed due to mouseover. If you still got any questions, just ask :)

Comment: Do you mean the Javascript settings? Basically I need to know what code I should put in the "onmouseout" section. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I mean to html / css settings . Check the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/hover/ - there's a great example which illustrates hover() functionality . In this example ,  in the mouse-over section , a new span was added to the li object. In the mouse-out section, this span was removed from the li object , and so we actually got back to the original settings of the li object. If you still got any questions, keep asking :)

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented your function and it works, but when the rotation resumes the content does not show up except for the one that was hovered over. I think the problem has to do with my "rotatecontent" function though.

Comment: Edit your message and paste the new code , I'll try to look for problem , good luck !